# How to reduce space between columns using kbl in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I am creating the following table in R Markdown as per the code below:

````
```{r table_r_3, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE}

library(kableExtra)

tab <- matrix(c("Description that takes 43 characters +123","2.89*** (1.12-3.90)","2.89*** (1.12-3.90)","2.89*** (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89*** (1.12-3.90)","2.89*** (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)",
                "Description that takes 43 characters +123","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)",
                "Description that takes 43 characters +123","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)",
                "Description that takes 43 characters +123","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)",
                "Description that takes 43 characters +123","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)",
                "Description that takes 43 characters +123","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)",
                "Description that takes 43 characters +123","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)",
                "Description that takes 43 characters +123","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)",
                "Description that takes 43 characters +123","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)",
                "Description that takes 43 characters +123","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)",
                "Description that takes 43 characters +123","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)",
              "Description that takes 43 characters +123","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)",
              "Description that takes 43 characters +123","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)","2.89 (1.12-3.90)"
              ), ncol=13, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(tab) <- c(' ','A1','A2','A1','A2','A1','A2','A1','A2','A1','A2','A1','A2')
rownames(tab) <- NULL
tab <- as.table(tab)

table_r_3_output <- kbl(tab, booktabs = T, linesep = "", row.names = 0, caption = "Results.") %>%
  kable_styling(font_size = 5, latex_options = "hold_position") %>%
add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Grp1 & Grp2" = 2, "Grp1" = 2, "Grp1 & Grp2" = 2, "Grp1" = 2, "Grp1 & Grp2" = 2, "Grp1" = 2)) %>%
add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Jan 2015 - Dec 2017" = 4, "Jan 2016 - Dec 2016" = 4, "Jan 2017 - Dec 2017" = 4),
                 escape = FALSE) %>%
  column_spec(1, width = "19em") %>%
  column_spec(c(2:13), width = "5em")

```
    
```{r table_r_3_final, echo=FALSE}
table_r_3_output
```
````

This gives me the following output:
[image]

I would like to reduce the space between columns, without changing the width (since I am already doing it below), does anyone know how to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: add this line `\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-5pt}` before the `table_r_3_final` chunk.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to set `full_width` value in `kable_styling()` in your code above to `FALSE` :

```
kable_styling(font_size = 5, latex_options = "hold_position", full_width = FALSE)
```

The result:

[image]